# Is Zener Diode a good choice for DC voltage regulation for a buck converter? And how should I use it?

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, zener

I have a buck converter that I want to use to step down the DC voltage from a UPS to 13V to power a CCTV set-up. The buck converter input is specified as 40V but the UPS output fluctuates to a max of 56V and 45 min. I want to use a Zener Diode at the output of the UPS before the buck converter to keep the input voltage from the UPS constant at 40V. Is this a good choice? And how do I set it up?

Comment: No, not a good idea.

Comment: In theory you can put a 18V Z-diode in series with the buck converter to subtract this voltage, but this is a very, very bad solution. The power losses in the diode would be enormous.

Comment: Just get a buck converter IC rated for 60 V input. There are plenty of those out there.

Comment: Zener as a regulator is a very bad idea.

Comment: Oh okay. wow, thanks, everyone. @Hearth, Yeah I was hoping to avoid additional costs since I have a Zener diode just lying around.

Comment: Current through Zener is the inverse of the current through the load, so when load goes to 0, full current goes through load, blowing Zener.  Only works for low, very stable loads.